# Martingale representation in practice

Tags: probability, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I have difficulties with the following exercise:

Given W a Brownian motion, $T > 0$ and $H = \int_0^T W_u^2 du,$ the task is to find a function g such that: $$H = \mathbb{E} [ H ] + \int_0^T g(u, W_u) dW_u$$

Do you have any hints? I have tried writing the integral that defines $H$ as Riemann sums and then play around, but I managed nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try applying Ito's formula to
$$ X_t=(T-t)W_t^2$$

Comment: That does the job. It's hard to guess the many ways you can use Ito. Thank you.

Comment: Here is one way to see where $X_t$ came from. By the martingale property of $W^2_u-u$ is is easy to see that $\Bbb E[H|\mathcal F_t]=\int_0^t W_u^2\,du+G(t,W_t)$, where $G(t,x) = (T-t)x^2+(T-t)^2/2$. At the same time, given that $H$ admits the martingale representation in terms of $g(u,W_u)$,  one has $\Bbb E[H|\mathcal F_t]=T^2/2+\int_0^t g(u,W_u)\,dW_u$. That is,
$$
\int_0^t W_u^2\,du+X_t+(T-t)^2/2=T^2/2+\int_0^t g(u,W_u)\,dW_u,\quad 0\le t\le T,
$$
revealing the relevance of the Ito expansion of $X_t$ (in particular its martingale part).